# Not found .map extension from node_modules in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular

I try to integrate angular to rails app. I extended assets folder by

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
```

and it's good work but my console has serveral messages error

> http://localhost:3000/assets/rxjs/Subject.js.map

Rails app couldn't `.map` extension how to load it

Answer (score 1):

Those are "javascript source map" files. If your `Subject.js` javascript file has been minimized/uglified, then you can generate and add a "map" file to let browsers know how to "unminimize"/"unuglify" your js file.

If the `Subject.js` file is written by you, then I guess your environment setup with different node.js and gulp.js modules has it enabled. Make sure those files are copied to your `/assets` folder as well.

Alternatively, you can disable them by removing special comment at the end of your javascript file:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=/assets/rxjs/Subject.js.map
```

Or, less likely, your server might be sending `X-SourceMap` header.